# How to create an input function , input_fn()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/input_fn/) tutorial from _tensorflow.org .
I am trying to correctly handle the *input_fn_*, to use as argument in *.fit()* .
I have created the classifier:

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat(tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
feature_columns=feature_cols,
hidden_units=[10, 10],
model_dir=("C:\\........\tmp"),
n_classes=2,
activation_fn=tf.sigmoid,
optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    )))
```

Then the input function:

```
def input_fn(data_set):
  feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values)
                  for k in FEATURES}
  labels = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL].values)
  return feature_cols, labels
```

Finally I have put *input_fn()* in *fit()* by:

```
classifier.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(training_set), steps=10)
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-938bcd2f929f> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(training_set), steps=10)

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_fn'
```

I don't know if it is about the *input_fn* definition, or the *fit* arguments

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SKCompat if you want to use input_fn, replace first line with:

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
```

And adjust parenthesis as needed.